# Installing phpmyadmin by sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin throws "Empty value for 'port' specified" error

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-16.04

This is the error I get:

```
                     Configuring phpmyadmin 
                                                                            │ 
  An error occurred while installing the database:                            

  mysql: [Warning] mysql: Empty value for 'port' specified. Will throw an     
  error in future versions ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local         
  MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) . Your        
  options are:                                                                
   * abort - Causes the operation to fail; you will need to downgrade,        
     reinstall, reconfigure this package, or otherwise manually intervene     
     to continue using it. This will usually also impact your ability to      
     install other packages until the installation failure is resolved.       
   * retry - Prompts once more with all the configuration questions           
     (including ones you may have missed due to the debconf priority          
    setting) and makes another attempt at performing the operation.          
  * retry (skip questions) - Immediately attempts the operation again,       

                                  <Ok>
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: First check whether you are able to log into mysql through terminal. If not, try to restart mysql service. and then check once again.

Comment: have you installed mysql first?

Comment: Try removing everything, then repeat the installation process.